# Capped performance over UDP (and sometimes TCP) in iPerf

Tags: tcp, udp, telnet, throughput, iperf

I can't seem to figure out what's wrong with my iPerf executable. I am trying to automate the execution of iPerf using a Telnet script (this is the one I am using https://github.com/ngharo/Random-PHP-Classes/blob/master/Telnet.class.php). I'd like to know what I can do to find the reason for the bottleneck, assuming the PHP script works as expected. Basically, if I run it manually over the command line, I get the rates desired however if I run it remotely using the script I get capped performance.

What I have tried is using tcpdump to output the logs while iperf is running and then reading it using Wireshark. All I can observe is that the time differences between the fragments are larger when using the script, which means the rates will be lower. I don't know what to do next after this. Any ideas what else I can look at/try? I've tried changing kernel values for buffer sizes using sysctl but this has no effect as running it manually always works anyway.

Note that I have tried to play around with all the iperf configuration options such as -w, -l, -b (I havent tried burst mode). No success.

Comment: Compare the environment variables between the command line and remote cases.

Comment: @SethNoble Seems like the iperf server slows down for some reason when done in the automated case. It just runs slower and cannot keep up with the packets coming in.

Comment: Understood: check the environment variables of the automated and interactive environments.  There may be some difference, perhaps not an obvious one, which changes the behavior of iperf.